# Query temporary table and Transaction log growing?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a project to just simple query (simple select). For that, there is many logic behind and I created  many temporary table inside the query (#).

Our database was facing a problem since last week, the size of the transaction file was big and just growing and the DBA shrinked the file but when I run my query today, I could not run my query again.

I checked the size of the transaction log and it's starting to grow again even without I do anything. I want to know if it is because I have many temporary table (#) in my query? or our DBA should maintain that? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should investigate how to make your query more efficient versus focusing on how to maintain the tlogs. Otherwise, the problem will persist.

Comment: So do you think creating a lot of temporary table will affect the size of transaction log? Do you have any idea how to make the query more efficient>

Comment: We'd have to see the queries....

Comment: Temporary tables should not be logged, even with full recovery on other databases.  Those operations should not be filling the log.

Comment: The code is really long but I want to summarize it a little bit here for you so you have the picture of it

Comment: Create table #temp0

Comment: Gordon Linoff :  Do you know the reason why the size of the  transaction file is still growing even though we do not query or do anything?

Comment: @GordonLinoff:Temporary tables logs its activities ,check here :https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server

Comment: @TheGameiswar . . . My statement was incomplete.  The recovery model is "simple", so it shouldn't fill the log (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365937(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually the log will be filled, but that space will be marked as empty/reusable once that transaction that created temp tables finishes. Quoting link You've provided: "tempdb log space is always automatically reclaimed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary tables logs it activities on TEMPDB,so the log growth will be only on TEMPDB..

you can use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) from Adam Machanic to more session allocations for tempdb

here is the query output from my system

[image]

if this is normal database and if you want to know what session can be causing more log growth,you can use this query

```
select DB_NAME(tr.database_id) as dbname,
       (database_transaction_log_bytes_used+ database_transaction_log_bytes_reserved)*1.0/1024 as 'Tlog_used_KB',
       ec.session_id,
       txt.text

        from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions tr
        join
        sys.dm_exec_requests ec
        on ec.transaction_id=tr.transaction_id
        cross apply
        sys.dm_exec_sql_text(Ec.sql_handle) txt
```

Normally TLOG Space will be reused,but if you are not seeeing that happening,it may be due to any of the reasons that might be [listed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space)

Comment: Thank you so much for your  answer. Actually ithe temporarydb transaction log is not growing the other database that I do not use for my query is  growing. Do you know what can cause the other database to grow even though we do not query anything from the database?

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Actually it is not the transaction log of temporarydb that grows but just  the transaction log of a normal database which I quite do not understand because I do not make change in the database , I just create the temporary # table in my query to get some field. Do you have any idea why the transaction log of the normal db is still growing even though now I stopped my query.